# Why does a yielded SQLAlchemy Session in a FastAPI dependency close once it goes out of scope?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, fastapi

In the [FastAPI docs](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/dependencies/dependencies-with-yield/) it is recommended to set up a SQLAlchemy database session dependency using a generator function like so:

```py
async def get_db():
    db = DBSession()
    try:
        yield db
    finally:
        db.close()
```

My question is why does the finally block ever get executed? I was under the impression that generator functions pause execution at each yield. Once the session object goes out of scope, shouldn't the execution of `get_db` be discarded with `db.close()` never having run?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you throw `breakpoint()` in your dependency before `try` and look at the call tree using `w` option you can see that for generator type function `next()`is called in `contextlib` module code:

```
[0]   c:\users\homeuser\.pyenv\pyenv-win\versions\3.7.9\lib\threading.py(890)_bootstrap()
-> self._bootstrap_inner()
[1]   c:\users\homeuser\.pyenv\pyenv-win\versions\3.7.9\lib\threading.py(926)_bootstrap_inner()
-> self.run()
[2]   c:\users\homeuser\.pyenv\pyenv-win\versions\3.7.9\lib\threading.py(870)run()
-> self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
[3]   c:\users\homeuser\.pyenv\pyenv-win\versions\3.7.9\lib\concurrent\futures\thread.py(80)_worker()
-> work_item.run()
[4]   c:\users\homeuser\.pyenv\pyenv-win\versions\3.7.9\lib\concurrent\futures\thread.py(57)run()
-> result = self.fn(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
[5]   c:\users\homeuser\.pyenv\pyenv-win\versions\3.7.9\lib\contextlib.py(112)__enter__()
-> return next(self.gen)
```

Notice that this `next()` call is being done inside `__enter__` special function that is used by context managers when using `with` keyword to open it.   Now if step forward through `yield` statement and wait until your breakpoint will step in the `finally` block where you can look at call tree using `w` once again:

```
[0]   c:\users\homeuser\.pyenv\pyenv-win\versions\3.7.9\lib\threading.py(890)_bootstrap()
-> self._bootstrap_inner()
[1]   c:\users\homeuser\.pyenv\pyenv-win\versions\3.7.9\lib\threading.py(926)_bootstrap_inner()
-> self.run()
[2]   c:\users\homeuser\.pyenv\pyenv-win\versions\3.7.9\lib\threading.py(870)run()
-> self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
[3]   c:\users\homeuser\.pyenv\pyenv-win\versions\3.7.9\lib\concurrent\futures\thread.py(80)_worker()
-> work_item.run()
[4]   c:\users\homeuser\.pyenv\pyenv-win\versions\3.7.9\lib\concurrent\futures\thread.py(57)run()
-> result = self.fn(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
[5]   c:\users\homeuser\.pyenv\pyenv-win\versions\3.7.9\lib\contextlib.py(119)__exit__()
-> next(self.gen)
```

Now you will notice that `next()` is called on your generator function when exiting from context manager object.

You're right about pausing, but state of function is also remembered. So when first `next()` in `__enter__` is called it yields your session object, then second `next()` call resumes function execution thus making it possible to enter inside `finally` block.

I think `@contextmanager` decorator is used somewhere in FastAPI implementation that takes care of dependencies thus making it possible to use generators in `Depends`.
Take a look at [this](https://realpython.com/introduction-to-python-generators/#understanding-the-python-yield-statement) article that takes pretty good explanation how Python generators work.

Comment: I appreciate the answer. I figured there was something going on under the hood with FastAPI dependencies that isn't obvious. I assume they have some kind of custom context manager implementation that runs `next()` on enter and exit.

I think there is also another reason why `finally` would get run, more general to generators. I'm going to post my own answer for that.

Answer (score 2):

devaerial posted a good answer about how `next()` is called during the enter and exit magic methods of the context manager that is implemented by FastAPI generator dependencies. However, there is another more general reason the `finally` block would execute that I wanted to post here.

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56063400/13242100) answer about generators more broadly. Say we have a generator function...

```py
def gen():
    yield 1
    print("test")
```

My output will be like so:

```py
>>> print(next(gen()))
1
```

However, if I modify my function using `try...finally`

```py
def gen():
    try:
        yield 1
    finally:
        print("test")
```

I will get this output:

```py
>>> print(next(gen()))
test
1
```

The `finally` block is guaranteed to be executed before garbage collection once the generator is destroyed.