# Strange behavior with contextmanager

Tags: python, python-3.x, contextmanager

Take a look at the following example:

```py
from contextlib import AbstractContextManager, contextmanager


class MyClass(AbstractContextManager):
    _values = {}

    @contextmanager
    def using(self, name, value):
        print(f'Allocating {name} = {value}')
        self._values[name] = value
        try:
            yield
        finally:
            print(f'Releasing {name}')
            del self._values[name]

    def __enter__(self):
        return self.using('FOO', 42).__enter__()

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        pass


with MyClass():
    print('Doing work...')
```

---

I would expect the above code to print the following:

```
Allocating FOO = 42
Doing work...
Releasing FOO
```

Instead, this is what is being printed:

```
Allocating FOO = 42
Releasing FOO
Doing work...
```

Why is `FOO` getting released eagerly?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [try-finally in Python 3 generator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56062909/try-finally-in-python-3-generator)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're creating two context managers here. Only one of those context managers is actually implemented correctly.

Your `using` context manager is fine, but you've also implemented the context manager protocol on `MyClass` itself, and the implementation on `MyClass` is broken. `MyClass.__enter__` creates a `using` context manager, enters it, returns what that context manager's `__enter__` returns, and then **throws the `using` context manager away**.

You don't exit the `using` context manager when `MyClass()` is exited. You never exit it at all! You throw the `using` context manager away. It gets reclaimed, and when it does, the generator gets `close` called automatically, as part of normal generator cleanup. That throws a `GeneratorExit` exception into the generator, triggering the `finally` block.

Python doesn't promise when this cleanup will happen (or indeed, if it will happen at all), but in practice, CPython's reference counting mechanism triggers the cleanup as soon as the `using` context manager is no longer reachable.

---

Aside from that, if `_values` is supposed to be an instance variable, it should be set as `self._values = {}` inside an `__init__` method. Right now, it's a class variable.

Comment: I think `_values` is supposed to be a dictionary that keeps track of different contexts via the key. But for the minimal example he just hard-coded a key.

Comment: This answer would be improved by showing how to code it correctly. The impression I get from the documentation is that you don't normally need to write your own `__enter__` and `__exit__` when you use `@contextmanager`, it takes care of that for you.

Comment: @Barmar: I can't tell enough about the intended use case to figure out what *would* be the "correct" way to write this. It'd probably involve getting rid of one of the context managers, but I don't know which, and there's a big difference between what the code looks like if you get rid of `using` or if you get rid of `__enter__` and `__exit__` on `MyClass`.