# Why do we need "try-finally" when using @contextmanager decorator?

Tags: python, python-3.x, contextmanager

I wonder why we need to use a try-finally when using a the [@contextmanager](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html) decorator.

The provided [example](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.contextmanager) suggests:

```py
from contextlib import contextmanager

@contextmanager
def managed_resource(*args, **kwds):
    resource = acquire_resource(*args, **kwds)
    try:
        yield resource
    finally:
        release_resource(resource)
```

It seems to me, however, that this will do the exact same thing:

```py
@contextmanager
def managed_resource(*args, **kwds):
    resource = acquire_resource(*args, **kwds)
    yield resource
    release_resource(resource)
```

I'm sure I must be missing something. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because a `finally` statement is guaranteed to run no matter what (except a power outage), before the code can terminate. So writing it like this guarantees that the resource is always released

Comment: So even when there's no second `next()` call?

Comment: @Kris yes, if you don't save a reference to the generator - see here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56063400/9490769

Answer (score 2):

`finally` makes sure that the code under it is always executed even if there's an exception raised:

```
from contextlib import contextmanager

@contextmanager
def exception_handler():
    try:
        yield
    finally:
        print("cleaning up")

with exception_handler():
    result = 10 / 0
```

If there were no try-finally, the above example wouldn't cleanup itself afterwards.