# Behaviour of try finally with a generator

Tags: python, loops, queue, generator, try-finally

I'm following the Effective Python course by Brett Slatkin on O'Reilly: https://learning.oreilly.com/videos/effective-python/9780134175249/

I've come across the following code snippet while learning about closable queues to concurrently handle synchronous actions like downloading/uploading/resizing data:

```
class ClosableQueue(Queue):
    SENTINEL = object()

    def close(self):
        self.put(self.SENTINEL)

    def __iter__(self):
        while True:
            try:
                item = self.get()

                if item is self.SENTINEL:
                    return 
                else:
                    yield item
            finally:
                self.task_done()
```

In the snippet above, the finally block is executed after every item is yielded from the queue.

However if we modify the iter function as follows:

```
class ClosableQueue(Queue):
    SENTINEL = object()
    
    def close(self):
        self.put(self.SENTINEL)

    def __iter__(self):
        try:
            item = self.get()

            if item is self.SENTINEL:
                return 
            else:
                yield item
        finally:
            self.task_done()
```

Then the finally block is executed after the iterator is exhausted, not after every yield.

I'm not able to clearly understand why this works as described. One possible explanation I came across while searching for an explanation is that the finally block for a generator is supposed to be executed when the generator is exhausted, however, since we have a while True in the first version, the generator is in theory always yielding values, so it is never exhausted, so the finally is run after each yield.

Please let me know if my understanding is correct, if not please provide a better explanation for the behaviour.

Thanks.

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56062909/try-finally-in-python-3-generator

Comment: Hi, I went through the post yesterday but it does not seem to explain why the finally is run post every yield if there is an enclosing while True

Answer (score 0):

```py
def generator_example():
        try:
            while True:
                print("Before yield")
                yield
                print("After yield")
        finally:
            print("In finally")

gen = generator_example()

next(gen)  # Outputs: Before yield
next(gen)  # Outputs: After yield\nBefore yield
```

The behaviour is not unexpected, Mark more comprehensively answers why.

In your code, after you yield and re-enter, the try's scope ends before the next iteration of the while loop starts.

In the update version, it won't enter the finally because the while loop never exits the original try block. Normally, we could expect a finite iterator to raise StopIteration and break out of the loop. in your case you'd need to break out of your while loop conditionally, ex:

```py
def generator_example():
        counter=0
        try:
            while True:
                if counter >= 2:
                     print("Breaking!")
                     break
                counter += 1
                print("Before yield")
                yield
                print("After yield")
        finally:
            print("In finally")

gen = generator_example()

next(gen)  # same
next(gen)  
next(gen)  # "In finally" printed then StopIteration raised by generator implicit return
```

About your second example, iteration ends after the first yield for me, same for the Temp class you asked about, consider this modification again:

```py
from queue import Queue


class ClosableQueue(Queue):
    SENTINEL = object()

    def close(self):
        self.put(self.SENTINEL)

    def __iter__(self):
        try:
            while (item := self.get()) != self.SENTINEL:
                yield item
        finally:
            self.task_done()


A = ClosableQueue()
A.put(1)
A.put(2)
A.put(3)
A.close()

for item in A:
    print(item)  # expects 1, 2, 3
```

Comment: Hi, this is starting to make some sense now, I now understand why the first snippet I provided works as expected: its because the try's scope ends before the next iteration of the while loop starts, however I'm still unclear on why in the second example I provided, the finally runs after all items in the queue are exhausted, and does not return after the first yield, lemme show you what I mean by taking your example:

Comment: `class Temp:`
    `def __iter__(self):`
        `counter=0`
        `try:`
            `if counter >= 2:`
                 `print("Breaking!")`
                 `return`
            `counter += 1`
            `print("Before yield", counter)`
            `yield`
            `print("After yield")`
        `finally:`
            `print("In finally")`

`gen = Temp()`

`for num in gen:`
    `print(num)`

Comment: Sorry for the bad formatting, but I modified your example a bit to represent the second example I provided, please explain why the iterator is exhausted after the first yield, because in the second example that I provided, which is very similar to this one, the iterator is exhausted after all items in the queue are yield / processed. Thanks.

Comment: I ran your second example, it always closes after the first yield for me as you expect. `A.put(1); A.put(2); A.put(3)` `for item in A: print(item)` only prints '1'

I added some more content to the body of my post related.

Comment: Basically, generators save their call state. When you yield you are still within that same try except, yielding itself doesn't cause the try except to go out of scope because yielding doesn't return the function. Instead, the function state is getting pushed onto some call stack to later restore - to continue executation right where the yield halted it, as if it never left scope. In the second case, after the first yield it will start execution from where that yield left off, which only leaves exiting the try/except left, then when the generator implicitly returns it raises StopIteration.

Comment: I think I was mistaking the finally in the second example to being run after all items have been processed, instead it runs after the first item is processed, so to sum it up, using a while True in the first example, we always yield the next item in the queue and ensure that stop iteration is not raised till we encounter sentinel

Comment: Yes. I might add,  `while (item := self.get()) != self.SENTINEL` Might seem weird, but I'd argue it's more explanatory than `while True`. While the item we get is not the sentinel, do whatever with the retrieved item.